# Why do I get different results when I run the same code in a TextChanged event as opposed to a Button Click?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I have a function that iterates through a Datagridview and finds any matches to the provided search query. 
It uses the "hits" it finds to paint a panel to the right of the datagridview showing where the hits are relative to the scrollbar.

When I run this code in a button click event, it works as expected.
When I run it in a text changed event, the code runs as expected then the panel clears itself out.

This only happens the first time the code is ran per debug session. The rest of the session, the text change event works fine and the panel retains it's painted sections as it should.

Originally, for development purposes, I had the code directly inside the button event handler. It was only when I placed the same code in a text changed event did I first see the issue.

I've since placed the code into its own function, calling it in both the button click and text changed event.

So it looks like this:

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Search();
}

private void TbSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Search();
}
```

"Search" contains:

```
private void Search()
{
    PanelClear();
    if (tbSearch.Text.Length > 2)
    {
       Searchy(tbSearch.Text);

        if (_hits.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var hit in _hits){PanelPaint_paint(hit);}
        }
    }
}
```

`PanelClear` contains:

```
private void PanelClear()
{
    //Clears the list of matches.
    _hits.Clear();
    //Invalidates my panel control. 
    panelPaint.Invalidate();
    //Hides a textbox
    tbTotal.Visible = false;
}
```

And `PanelPaint_paint`:

```
private void PanelPaint_paint(Hit hit)
{
    Graphics g = panelPaint.CreateGraphics();
    Color xx = ext.myColor;
    Color saved = hit.color;
    if (saved != Color.Empty) xx = hit.color;
    Pen myPen = new Pen(xx) { Width = 1 };
    int dgvl = dgvEvents.Rows.Count;
    int pnll = panelPaint.Height;
    int hitl = hit.RowNum;
    double percent = ((double)hitl / (double)dgvl) * pnll;
    float x = (float)percent;
    g.DrawLine(myPen, 1, x, panelPaint.Width, x);
    dgvEvents.Rows[hit.RowNum].Cells[2].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle
    {
        BackColor = xx,
        ForeColor = invert(xx)
    };
    extrabuttons(true);
    tbTotal.Text = allhits().Count.ToString();
}
```

So here's a gif showing what happens when I run the search in a simple Button Click:
[Panel Paint on Button Click event](https://s.put.re/eapQGPzt.gif)

You'll notice, I click the button, and the panel retains its paint.

Here's what happens if I put that same code into a TextChanged event handler:
[Panel Paint on TextChanged event](https://s.put.re/28LQ2iis.gif)

It doesn't search until it hits 3 characters, so you'll see once I enter the 'U' it runs the search, paints the Panel, but then immediately clears it. All other searches, like when I add the 'E', or backspace back to 'U' work fine.

Comment: I can't say why it's working differently. But there is a simple rule - do the painting *only* inside `Paint` event of the control which needs painting and there will not be side effects/strange behaviors.

Comment: @myaccountname Jimi is asking you to copy the source code for the `PanelPaint_paint()` method and paste it into your question. You can edit the question to add more text.

Comment: @myaccountname It's like consulting a doctor. Don't be embarrassed. He's seen worse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create the Graphics object this way:

```
Graphics g = panelPaint.CreateGraphics();
```

what you draw using this object will not persist. A control generates a new Graphics object each time it's redrawn (invalidated). This happen often. This means that the drawing needs to be refreshed each time a Control is invalidated, using the current Graphics object provided by the `Paint` event's [PaintEventArgs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.painteventargs). (You'll often find this recommendation in the MSDN Docs and in many question in StackOverflow).

For this reason you always perform all the painting in the `Paint` handler (or the overridden [OnPaint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onpaint) method).

Different events can cause a Control to be Invalidated (repainted): when the Form is minimized/maximized, when another object/Window is moved on top of it, when the System braodcasts a settings changed message (and others) and many other conditions.

Also when the Forms's [AutoValidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.autovalidate) feature triggers it:

> Gets or sets a value that indicates whether controls in this container
>   will be automatically validated when the focus changes.

Try to modify the code as follows. Note that I cannot test this code because I don't have the object and some of the values used here.  I hope this can help you to adjust your code.

```
private void Search() {
    _hits.Clear();
    tbTotal.Visible = false;
    if (tbSearch.Text.Length < 3) return;
    Searchy(tbSearch.Text);
    if (_hits.Count == 0) return;

    foreach (var hit in _hits) {
        dgvEvents.Rows[hit.RowNum].Cells[2].Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle {
            BackColor = hit.color == Color.Empty ? ext.myColor : hit.color,
            ForeColor = invert(BackColor)
        };
    }
    panelPaint.Invalidate();
    extrabuttons(true);
    tbTotal.Text = allhits().Count.ToString();
}

private void panelPaint_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (_hits.Count == 0) return;
    e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
    foreach (var hit in _hits) {
        PaintPanel(hit, e.Graphics);
    }
}

private void PaintPanel(Hit hit, Graphics g)
{
    using (Pen myPen = new Pen(hit.color == Color.Empty ? ext.myColor : hit.color, 1)) {
        float percent = ((float)hit.RowNum / dgvEvents.Rows.Count) * (float)panelPaint.Height;
        g.DrawLine(myPen, 1, percent, panelPaint.Width, percent);
    }
}
```